# HTML select option values from mysql db via php are not coming properly inside the tag

Tags: html

I am creating a html form, in which **select** dropdown is used.
The values in select are coming from MySql db using PHP.
The problem is, the values from DB are not coming inside the select options, but printing outside of it, while i am writing code like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if ($result != 0) {
echo '<select name="name" >';

    $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for ($i=0;$i<$num_results;$i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $name = $row['name'];
        echo '<option value="' .$name. '">' .$name. '</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
}
```

But when i put one more select, the values comes inside of the select options.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if ($result != 0) {
#Extra select#
echo '<select>';
##############
echo '<select name="name" >';

    $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for ($i=0;$i<$num_results;$i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $name = $row['name'];
        echo '<option value="' .$name. '">' .$name. '</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
}
```

But of-course, there is one **select** box coming for no use.
What is wrong in this code ?

Comment: It might help if you look at the HTML that gets output (the raw output in the source code, not the parsed output in the element inspector) instead of just describing how it renders in the browser.

Comment: Wild speculation: You forgot the `>` on the end of the tag before the `<select>`.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/nu/ is your friend. Use it.